# Where can I get Toad syntax coloring schemes?

Tags: toad, skins

I am a big fan of the light colors on a dark background color scheme for programming - which is unfortunately  not what Quest's Toad comes with by default.

I notice that it is possible to export and import settings under the language management window, and I know that Toad has a large level of community involvement.  So I assume there must be some location where people are posting their custom coloring schemes.  However, in part because I don't know what the Toad guys call them (skins? colorization? themes?) and in part because its so hard to Google Toad +skins I cannot for the life of me find them.

Does anyone know if there is such a place so I don't have to set the colors by hand?

Comment: I've revised my answer entirely - I listed a packaged color theme available from GitHub, and a forum on toad extensions where folks trade "color themes" (their official name). Trying hard to earn Andrew's bounty here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*UPDATED ENTIRELY:*

1. **What's the official name?**

   The file extension (`.dvtcolortheme`) suggests `"Color Theme"` or `"DWT Color Theme"` are the official names. Most users on Toad forums seem to use the same terminology.
2. **Where are they shared?**

   There does not seem to be a dedicated site for sharing color themes. However, there were a couple forums on [ToadWorld](http://www.toadworld.com/), and [ToadForOracle](http://toadfororacle.com/) where folks were talking about swapping these color theme files. I would suggest hopping on the forum and asking if others have files to share or know of any repository sites.
3. **Available Color Themes**

   <s>* Nocturnal theme on GitHub: https://github.com/grng/Nocturnal-Toad-Color-Scheme</s>
   [image: Nocturnal Toad Color Scheme]

   <s>* A nice dark-background theme: http://toadfororacle.com/thread.jspa?messageID=93203</s>
4. **Rolling-your-own**

   I know you did not want to create your own, but it looks a lot easier than either of us expected. The `.dwtcolortheme` settings file is just XML.

   I suggest visiting http://studiostyl.es/ - as it's a large repository of Visual Studio themes. Find a thumbnail you like, take a screen shot, and use a color picker to capture the values. Plop them in your XML settings file and you are ready to go.

Comment: See Karan's answer below. They are spot on. .dvtcolortheme files are not used at all by Toad for Oracle and it is impossible to "theme" Toad and share/download/install syntax highlighting themes. I don't have enough rep to down vote this answer, but it is incorrect other than the "roll your own" suggestion which you need to do using Karan's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Go to View -> Toad Options. Click Editor -> Behavior. There is a button called Syntax Highlighting. On the Highlighting Tab (opens by default) is a list of styles, clicking on the style will show the options selected for that style...

For example in my setup (which is my install default), Reserved Words are blue, Comments green, Strings Red, etc.

Scroll through and you'll see the options, and you can change as necessary for your needs.

Comment: The question was "so I don't have to set the colors by hand"

Comment: Despite the downvote (I voted you up!) for Karan's answer, they are spot on. There are no themes to share. .dvtcolortheme extensions are for some other product. Syntax Highlighting is stored in LexLib.lxl in your User Files folder. In addition it stores code templates, lexer rules for identification of language tokens, etc. There is no way to same a theme and share with anyone else, unfortunately. This will be coming in future release. Syntax Highlighting will be broken out, separate from other settings and possibly sensitive data (code templates) so that you can share with others.

Answer (score 4):

The right file for new versions of TOAD is **EditorLexers.xml**.

For version 12.9 is here

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Dell\Toad for Oracle\12.9\User Files

instead for version 12.11 is here

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\12.11\User Files

[Here you can download my dark theme](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8C-yO8R_DFCc2VSUjRSc2NQUzA/view?usp=sharing)

Enjoy!

Update: it works also in version 13.0.

Comment: Please post your XML in SO directly, one day your link might be dead...

Answer (score 4):

I have created a schema similar to Visual Studio 2017 dark theme

You can download it from: [EditorLexers.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lREZ-Wg3a5ijfAlyvsoENmq_kJEoY1aB/view?usp=sharing)

You need to replace the file located at:

```
C:\Users\[YOUR_USER]\AppData\Roaming\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\13.1\User Files
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please [edit] the XML file directly into your answer, to avoid the problem of the link going dead. I can't do it for you because of licensing restrictions. (If you put it in the body of the answer, it becomes licensed as [CC by-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), like all content on Stack Overflow.)